# SqlDataReader.GetString Error: Invalid Arguments

Tags: c#, ado.net

When I run my problem, it shows this error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments.

My code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionClass.connectionclass);
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlDataReader dr;
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
string query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE Name = '"+comboBox1.Text+"'";
        com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string abc = dr.GetString("Name");

        }

    }
```

Comment: ok...i have searched for the answer and tried but the problem persists.

Comment: Why get all columns if you need only one?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: i removed other columns, it was just to describe my problem.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should supply the column ordinal number, not the column name to the [`SqlDataReader.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var ordinal = dr.GetOrdinal("Name");
while (dr.Read())
{
    string abc = dr.GetString(ordinal);

}
```

Comment: i did it by this `dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Name"));`

Comment: @Ali: that can have a serious performance impact. Listen to Martin (he has some reputation on this site so he knows...).